# Program ending in the middle of printf, but not in GDB

Tags: c

Really strange issue here, when I run this code through `GDB`, it runs fine. However if I run it normally, the program terminates in the middle of a `printf`. No seg fault or anything, it returns exit success.

I put in the line `printf("\nDone\n");` to see if it was just the loop ending, but that line never executes, and if I move it, then the location where `printf` stops changes.

```
void remove_dup() {
    int i, j;
    Dist origin_dist[sgt_head.len];
    Sgt_Node *s_n = &sgt_head;
    for (i = 0; i < sgt_head.len; i++) {
        s_n = s_n->ptr;
        origin_dist[i].dist = great_circle(s_n->sgt->loc, origin);
        origin_dist[i].sgt = s_n->sgt;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < sgt_head.len; i++) {
        printf("  %f %s\n", origin_dist[i].dist, origin_dist[i].sgt->obs.id);
    }
    qsort(origin_dist, sgt_head.len, sizeof(Dist), comp_dist);
    printf("Sorted Array:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < sgt_head.len; i++) {
        printf("  %f %s\n", origin_dist[i].dist, origin_dist[i].sgt->obs.id);
    }

    int duplicate = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sgt_head.len;) {
        double sep = origin_dist[i + 1].dist - origin_dist[i].dist;
        if (sep <= 0.02 && origin_dist[i + 1].sgt->type == origin_dist[i].sgt->type) {
            double gcd = great_circle(origin_dist[i].sgt->loc, origin_dist[i + 1].sgt->loc);
            if (gcd <= 0.02) {
                char type[10];
                int count = 1;
                location avg;
                avg.lat = 0.0;
                avg.lng = 0.0;
                if (origin_dist[i].sgt->type == 'P') {
                    strcpy(type, "Porpoise");
                } else {
                    strcpy(type, "Dolphins");
                }
                printf("\nMultiple %s:\n    Obs. lat.      lng.\n", type);
                printf("    %s %f %f\n", origin_dist[i].sgt->obs.id, origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lat, origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lng);
                avg.lat += origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lat;
                avg.lng += origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lng;
                do {
                    if (i != sgt_head.len - 1) {
                        i++;
                        count++;
                        sep = origin_dist[i + 1].dist - origin_dist[i].dist;
                        printf("    %s %f %f\n", origin_dist[i].sgt->obs.id, origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lat, origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lng);
                        avg.lat += origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lat;
                        avg.lng += origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lng;
                    }
                } while(sep <= 0.02 && i < sgt_head.len - 1);
                avg.lat /= count;
                avg.lng /= count;
                printf("Count:  %d, Average Location: %f, %f\n", count, avg.lat, avg.lng);
                i++;
            } else {
                char type[10];
                if (origin_dist[i].sgt->type == 'P') {
                    strcpy(type, "Porpoise");
                } else {
                    strcpy(type, "Dolphin");
                }
                printf("\nSingle %s:\n    Obs. lat. lng.\n", type);
                printf("    %s %f %f\n", origin_dist[i].sgt->obs.id, origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lat, origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lng);
                i++;
            }
        } else {
            char type[10];
            if (origin_dist[i].sgt->type == 'P') {
                strcpy(type, "Porpoise");
            } else {
                strcpy(type, "Dolphin");
            }
            printf("\nSingle %s:\n    Obs. lat. lng.\n", type);
            printf("    %s %f %f\n", origin_dist[i].sgt->obs.id, origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lat, origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lng);
            i++;
        } 
    printf("\nDone\n");
    }
}
```

I have no idea what to do here, I'm not doing anything funky with pointers here (I think).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Such as which `printf` is stops?  Does it happens to be the same `printf` or different every time you run the program?

Comment: Its the same `printf` each time, but if I move the `printf("\nDone\n");` line, then the culprit changes. With the code above, it fails with this output: 
    CB05 52.738836 -5.392516
    CB04 52.738836 -5.392553
    CB06 52.739144 -5.
RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 1m 8s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms

Comment: Looks like a heisenbug (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug#Heisenbug). Apart from that, I'm missing the declarations of the types/global variables used in the code. I think, your best bet would be to run your program  with valgrind, it will likely give you a pretty direct pointer at the bug.

Comment: You've got a loop `for (i = 0; i < sgt_head.len; )`. And in the body of the loop, you use `i+1` as an index. That may or may not be the source of the crash, but it's certainly a bug.

Comment: I also have the special case `if (i != sgt_head.len - 1)` to account for that ;)

Comment: That's way down in the `do` loop. I'm talking about the first line after the `for` loop, `double sep = origin_dist[i+1] ...` In fact, you're using `[i+1]` in the first three lines after the `for` loop.

Comment: That does seem like it should give an error, but I ran it with data that should force the error, and it didn't, so I have handled that somewhere...

Comment: the use of great circle distance will NOT be usable to determine if two points are close together.  Rather use the actual latitude and longitude of each pair of points to determine if the points are close together.  I.E. if ([i]legA-[i+1]legA) <= 0.02 && ([i]legB-[i]legB) <= 0.02 then consider the points to be the same.  Dont use great circle because the distance can be the same irregardless of the compass point from the origin.

Comment: the probable cause of the problem is accessing an array outside the boundaries of that array.  The stopping in the middle of a printf() is just that is when the illegal access occurs.  Moving a printf() changes the memory layout of the program.. Since accessing outside the boundary of an array is undefined behaviour, the bad behaviour will change as the content of the program is modified.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but if I put the `printf("\nDone\n");` in a certain place, the `printf` stops halfway through printing a `double` (i.e. it prints: 5.)

Comment: You clearly need a function to handle the 'it is a porpoise or a dolphin' code, probably with consistent pluralization (the plural of porpoise is porpoises).  Maybe `const char *species_name(char type, int num) { static const char *types[2][2] = { { "Porpoises", "Porpoise" }, { "Dolphins", "Dolphin" } }; int i = (type == 'P') ? 0 : 1; int n = (num == 1) ? 1 : 0; return types[i][n]; }`.

Answer (score 1):

These two lines:

```
double gcd = great_circle(origin_dist[i].sgt->loc, origin_dist[i + 1].sgt->loc);
if (gcd <= 0.02) {
```

should probably be:

```
double gcd = fabs(great_circle(origin_dist[i].sgt->loc, origin_dist[i + 1].sgt->loc));
if (gcd <= 0.02) {
```

The following is full of notes/comments and modest changes to the posted code.
    Please read the comments embedded in the code.  Because the basic 
    algorithm is faulty.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

struct location
{
    float lat;
    float lng;
};

void remove_dup()
{
    int i;
    //int j; // raises compiler warning about unused variable
    Dist origin_dist[sgt_head.len];
    Sgt_Node *s_n = &sgt_head; // get address of head of linked list

    for (i = 0; i < sgt_head.len; i++)
    {
        // step to next entry in linked list
        s_n = s_n->ptr;
        // calculate distance
        // this has problem because great_circle() distance
        // does not take into account the radial of the compass
        // only the arc distance over the earths' surface
        // suggest loc.lat -origin.lat --> leg-a and loc.lng - origin.lng --> leg-b
        // and save results in origin_dist[i].dist
        origin_dist[i].dist = great_circle(s_n->sgt->loc, origin);
        // update struct  Dist array entry
        origin_dist[i].sgt = s_n->sgt;
    } // end for

    for (i = 0; i < sgt_head.len; i++)
    {
        printf("  %f %s\n", origin_dist[i].dist, origin_dist[i].sgt->obs.id);
    } // end for

    qsort(origin_dist, sgt_head.len, sizeof(Dist), comp_dist);

    printf("Sorted Array:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < sgt_head.len; i++)
    {
        printf("  %f %s\n", origin_dist[i].dist, origin_dist[i].sgt->obs.id);
    } // end for

    //int duplicate = 0; // raises warning about unused variable
    // step through local array, skipping duplicates
    for (i = 0; i < sgt_head.len;)
    {
        // suggest this line be changed to use saved leg-a and leg-b (from above)
        double sep = fabs(origin_dist[i + 1].dist - origin_dist[i].dist);

        if ((sep <= 0.02)
            &&
            (origin_dist[i + 1].sgt->type == origin_dist[i].sgt->type))
        {
            double gcd = fabs(great_circle(origin_dist[i].sgt->loc, origin_dist[i + 1].sgt->loc));
            if (gcd <= 0.02)
            {
                char type[10];
                int count = 1;
                struct location avg;
                avg.lat = 0.0;
                avg.lng = 0.0;

                if (origin_dist[i].sgt->type == 'P')
                {
                    strcpy(type, "Porpoise");
                }
                else
                {
                    strcpy(type, "Dolphins");
                } // end if

                printf("\nMultiple %s:\n    Obs. lat.      lng.\n", type);

                for(; i < (sgt_head.len -1); i++ )
                {
                    printf("    %s %f %f\n", origin_dist[i].sgt->obs.id, origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lat, origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lng);
                    avg.lat += origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lat;
                    avg.lng += origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lng;
                    count++;
                    sep = fabs(origin_dist[i + 1].dist - origin_dist[i].dist);
                    if( sep > 0.02 ) break;
                }  // end for

                avg.lat /= count;
                avg.lng /= count;
                printf("Count:  %d, Average Location: %f, %f\n", count, avg.lat, avg.lng);
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                char type[10];
                if (origin_dist[i].sgt->type == 'P')
                {
                    strcpy(type, "Porpoise");
                }
                else
                {
                    strcpy(type, "Dolphin");
                }

                printf("\nSingle %s:\n    Obs. lat. lng.\n", type);
                printf("    %s %f %f\n", origin_dist[i].sgt->obs.id, origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lat, origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lng);
                i++;
            } // end if
        }
        else
        {
            char type[10];
            if (origin_dist[i].sgt->type == 'P')
            {
                strcpy(type, "Porpoise");
            }
            else
            {
                strcpy(type, "Dolphin");
            } // end if

            printf("\nSingle %s:\n    Obs. lat. lng.\n", type);
            printf("    %s %f %f\n", origin_dist[i].sgt->obs.id, origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lat, origin_dist[i].sgt->loc.lng);
            i++;
        } // end if
    } // end for
    printf("\nDone\n");
} // end function: remove_dup
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of this change?